# SQL: Find highest number if its in nvarchar format containing special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull the record containing the highest value, specifically I only need the value from that field. The problem is that the column is nvarchar format that contains a mix of numbers and special characters. The following is just an example:

```
PK      | Column 2 (nvarchar)
-------------------
1       | .1.1.
2       | .10.1.1
3       | .5.1.7
4       | .4.1.
9       | .10.1.2
15      | .5.1.4
```

Basically, because of natural sort, the items in column 2 are sorted as strings. So instead of returning the PK for the row containing ".10.1.2" as the highest value i get the PK for the row that contains ".5.1.7" instead.

I attempted to write some functions to do this but it seems what I've written looked way more complicated than it should be. Anyone got something simple or complicated functions are the only way?

I want to make clear that I'm trying to grab the PK of the record that contains the highest Column 2 value.

Comment: Is '.10.1' bigger than '.5.1.' because 10 > 5 or because 101 > 51?

Comment: the values are basically period delimited. so 10 > 5 yes

Comment: the first set of numbers are the parents and the second set of numbers are children to it's respective parent.

Comment: You said this was just an example. What values are allowed?

Comment: Hm what if you just trim the surounded dots and order by that with limit 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query might return what you desire

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(Column2, '.', '') as INT)) FROM table
```

Comment: This sort of works. It's my fault though, I wasn't specific enough. I'll edit my question. Thank you for the response though